# How to allow rapid post requests on Google-App?

Tags: java, android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up an android order taking application, and need to store the orders in google sheets. It works, but until I added the post request function in a for loop. So I fixed this by adding a delay in the for loop. However, is there any other way to do this? Because each time I submit an order the app lags until the for loop has finished.

I've added a thread.sleep to avoid this problem like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++){
    String itemName = order.get(i);
    String addOn = addOns.get(i);
    String quantity = order.get(i);
    quantity = quantity.substring(quantity.length() -  2, quantity.length() - 1);
    itemName = itemName.substring(0, itemName.length() - 4);

    System.out.println("Item ID: " + i + " " + itemName + " " + addOn + " " + quantity + " " + orderId );
    try{
        Thread.sleep(550); //This is the delay I added.
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        //do stuff
    }

    addItemToSheet(itemName,addOn,quantity,orderId);
}

    if (null != getActivity()) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).clearOrderList();
    }
```

Here is the google app:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SPREADSHEET URL");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Items'); 

function doPost(e){
  var action = e.parameter.action;

  if(action == 'addItem'){
    return addItem(e);
  }

}


function addItem(e){

  var date =  new Date();

  var id  =  sheet.getLastRow(); 

  var orderNum = e.parameter.orderNum;

  var itemName = e.parameter.itemName;

  var quantity = e.parameter.quantity;

  var extra = e.parameter.extra;



  sheet.appendRow([date,id,orderNum,itemName,quantity,extra]);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

}
```

Is there anything I can do to either the java loop or google app, so I can avoid using thread.sleep which freezes my app until the operation is done? Maybe an alternative way to delay in java? or a faster operation in google apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, I would recommend multi-threading.

> Multithreading is a Java feature that allows concurrent execution of
>   two or more parts of a program for maximum utilization of CPU. Each
>   part of such program is called a thread. So, threads are light-weight
>   processes within a process.

This way your application will continue to run in a thread while you POST request is being handled in a different thread. Please bear in mind that in order to  `wait()`, and `notify()` methods.

The methods above are used to control your workflow.

- *wait()*: This method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
- *notify()*: This method wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.

More details about multi-threading in Java, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-java/).

[Here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/wait-notify-and-notifyall-methods/) you shall find more details about the methods mentioned above.